# Old computer game about a robot and questions

Tags: identify-this-game, game-cartridge

I'm trying to remember an old game I used to play as a kid.  It may have been a Commodore 64 game, not sure.  All I remember was you answered questions like for math or something like that and as you got questions correctly, it helped build your robot friend.  I remember it was a cartridge game that slipped in the side of a keyboard.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Minor query: how certain are you about the side of the keyboard? The C64 cartridge port is at the back, behind the keyboard.

Comment: The [Atari ST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_ST) has the cartridge port at the left side.

Comment: ... and the ST had a game which sounds a little like the description, [Robot Attack](https://www.mobygames.com/game/atari-st/robot-attack), except that the aim is to prevent small robots from building a large killer robot. (Apparently not on cartridge though.)

Comment: The ST also never had any games released on cartridge.

Comment: The cartridge port on the TI 99/4a was on the side of the keyboard. Was it a hangman game?

Comment: Also, I think the TRS-80 Color Computer has the cartridge port on the right side.

Comment: It'd be massively digressive, but I'm now wondering whether there's a connection between the maths-puzzle Atari ST Robot Attack ( https://www.mobygames.com/images/shots/l/871021-robot-attack-atari-st-screenshot-robot-construction-under.png ) and the lightgun action title that was bundled with the ZX Spectrum for a bit ( https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-OoDnCiTU6Ig/UKON7-Px1CI/AAAAAAAAA1w/K82pWh3bFGc/s1600/robotattackgame.gif ).

Comment: Also, add the TI-99/4[a] to the list of computers with a cartridge port at the side of the keyboard — in that case on the righthand side of the keyboard and _on top_ of the case: https://www.nightfallcrew.com/wp-content/gallery/texas-instruments-ti-994a-navarones-widget-multi-cartridges/20160826_163246.JPG

Comment: Atari 1200 had a side-slot (to many complaints).

Comment: Could it have been Rocky's Boots?

Comment: Is it possibly [VTech Socrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTech_Socrates)? It had a robot buddy, educational questions, and a keyboard controller, though the cartridge didn't go in the side of the keyboard. [Here's a video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lb5Im7lwc6g)